# Python won't print anything past my def in my Text Adventure

Tags: python, function, printing

```
#Asks player for their name and whether they wish to enter or not
character_name = input(" Welcome to The Tenabris Manor, what is your 
name?:")
print("")
print(" The towering gates stand before you to the large Manor, do you 
enter?")
print("")
inp = ""
while inp != "enter" and inp != "leave":
inp = input(" enter enter or leave: ")
if inp != "enter" and inp != "leave":
    print(" You must type enter or leave")

if inp == "enter":
print(" You push with all your might on the large gates, it swings open with 
a loud clunk.")
if inp == "leave":
print("")
print(" You turn around and go back, probably for the best.")
print("")
print(" Your character", character_name, "turned back and never returned.")
input(" Press enter to exit")
SystemExit("")

def choose_room():
#key = False is so the person does not have the key until going upstairs
global key
key = False
while True: 
    print("")
    print(" Bookshelfs line the walls, a staircase is to the left and a door 
is straight ahead.")
    print("")
    print(" Type 'a' to: Go up the stairs")
    print(" Type 'b' to: To go through the door")
    print(" Type 'c' to: To check the bookshelfs")
    ans = input("")
    if ans=='a':
        print(" You walk up the creaking stairs")
        print(" At the top of the spiral staircase is a small observatory.")
        print(" Looking around on some of stacks of books littering the room  
you")
        print(" find a small key!")
        key = True
        continue
    elif ans=='b':
#The door detects whether the key is True or not/they have the key or not.
         if key == True:
             print(" You open the door with the small key.")
         elif key == False:
             print(" The door is locked, you will need a key to go through 
it.")
             continue
             return
             choose_room()
         else:
             print("The door is locked, you will need a key to go through 
it.")
             continue
             return
             choose_room()

    else:
        ans == 'c'
        print(" You look through the thousands of books.")
        print(" None of them interest you.")
        continue
        return
    choose_room()
```

Excuse my terrible Coding, this is my first project and I am surprised it works in the first place.

Also this is my first post on stack overflow.

My problem is this code worked perfectly did everything I needed it to, but then when I went to add some more detail to it, I decided to do that later and deleted everything I "added" now the code doesn't run anything but the first part before def choose_room():

No error message appears when I run it, it just does the first part then ignores the bit at "def choose_room():" completely.

Well that's all I can think of to add that might help find the cause. Next time I will make a copy of the file before changing anything so this doesn't happen again.

If nobody can find what the problem is, I will just try to remake the program from scratch again.

Comment: Looks like you've got some indentation to fix :-) Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @Mangohero1's correct. I ran your code no problems after fixing your indentation. Specifically, after `def choose_room`, everything should be indented over to indicate it's part of that function (except the call to `choose_room` at the end)

Comment: Trivial, but you shouldn't call `choose_room()` inside `choose_room` because this type of recursion might cause problems.

Comment: I'd disagree @VasilisG., if that function drives the game, then it would make sense to continually choose rooms in it's current state. As he expands, however, he'd want to have a main game loop with actions performed in that loop instead, but this is a decent enough start.

Comment: @NathanBurgess Not in Python; it's far better to use a loop instead of recursion for simple iteration. Worse, this recursive call is *in* an infinite while loop, although the loop will never actually iterate.

Comment: I agree that a loop is better and that currently his recursion has no exit condition, but I don't see any problem calling it like this here. In fact, it's behaving exactly as a loop currently (minus an exit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, indentation is part of the syntax, so if you have things improperly indented your code won't behave as you would expect it to.

Corrected indentation:

```
#Asks player for their name and whether they wish to enter or not
character_name = input(" Welcome to The Tenabris Manor, what is your name?:")
print("")
print(" The towering gates stand before you to the large Manor, do you enter?")
print("")
inp = ""
while inp != "enter" and inp != "leave":
    inp = input(" enter enter or leave: ")
    if inp != "enter" and inp != "leave":
        print(" You must type enter or leave")

    if inp == "enter":
        print(" You push with all your might on the large gates, it swings open with a loud clunk.")
    if inp == "leave":
        print("")
        print(" You turn around and go back, probably for the best.")
        print("")
        print(" Your character", character_name, "turned back and never returned.")
        input(" Press enter to exit")
        SystemExit("")

def choose_room():
    #key = False is so the person does not have the key until going upstairs
    global key
    key = False
    while True: 
        print("")
        print(" Bookshelfs line the walls, a staircase is to the left and a door is straight ahead.")
        print("")
        print(" Type 'a' to: Go up the stairs")
        print(" Type 'b' to: To go through the door")
        print(" Type 'c' to: To check the bookshelfs")
        ans = input("")
        if ans=='a':
            print(" You walk up the creaking stairs")
            print(" At the top of the spiral staircase is a small observatory.")
            print(" Looking around on some of stacks of books littering the room you")
            print(" find a small key!")
            key = True
            continue
        elif ans=='b':
             #The door detects whether the key is True or not/they have the key or not.
             if key == True:
                 print(" You open the door with the small key.")
             elif key == False:
                 print(" The door is locked, you will need a key to go through it.")
                 continue
                 return
                 choose_room()
             else:
                 print("The door is locked, you will need a key to go through it.")
                 continue
                 return
                 choose_room()

        else:
            ans == 'c'
            print(" You look through the thousands of books.")
            print(" None of them interest you.")
            continue
            return
choose_room()
```

Answer (score -1):

You defined the function `choose_room()` but never used/called it. It would go something like this.

```
#...
if inp == "enter":
    print(" You push with all your might on the large gates, it swings open with a loud clunk.")
    choose_room()
#...
```

Make sure to define the function before calling it. Place the `def choose_room():...` on top of the script or before actually `choose_room`

Comment: He does call it, the very last line of the file.